# Confused about Applications of huffman tree

Tags: algorithm

What is real life application of huffman tree algorithm? how is it greedy approach?
 i need brief explanation on use of huffman tree in computer science problem solving, i want to know where can i use this algorithm in my day to day programming.

Comment: You could have just looked it up. You know that, right? Making a stack overflow account and asking this question is literally more effort.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. programmers.stackexchange.com is a better place for more conceptual questions, but what you're asking may just be too broad and open-ended for the StackExchange format anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Huffman tree assigns a variable length bit pattern with the prefix property to each of a set of tokens based on their distribution in such a way as to produce a very compact output encoding. Net effect: the byte version of your token stream has a high entropy. Which means it is coded very efficiently.

Imagine you had a thousand tokens that might appear in the stream. But one of then occurs 40% of the time, the rest being approximately equally distributed. With a Huffman tree you'd end up storing that one in a smaller number of bits than the others. It's as though you'd invented a shorthand for it except that the tree does that across the range of probabilities. The more likely a token, the fewer the bits.

It's therefore classically used in compression. Something like GZip does a step to try to describe the original data in a smaller number of tokens, then uses Huffman to try to make the stream of tokens it has produced as small as possible.

It's greedy because the tree is built by repeatedly selecting the most probable remaining token from the input set.